# the intuition behind eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm learning linear algebra from scratch and I'm trying to grasp the intuition behind the formula that's used to operate with a diagonalized transformation.

As far as I understand, the process begins, roughly speaking, like this: you first get the eigenvectors of a transformation, then change the basis of a vector x with this matrix (you assume it exists, but you don't include it in the computation), then apply the original transformation, then apply the inverse of the change of basis, and then you got the diagonalized matrix. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np    
# some vector
vec = np.array([1,1])
# some transformation
t = np.array([[1,1],
              [0,2]])
# change of basis matrix (with the eigenvectors of t)
cb = np.array([[1,1],
               [0,1]])
# inverse of cb
cb_inv = np.linalg.inv(cb)
# eigenbasis (cb_inv*t*cb)
eb = np.dot(cb_inv,np.dot(t,cb)) # array([[1., 0.],
                                 #        [0., 2.]])
```

This doesn't sound so crazy to me. But what I can't wrap my head around is why the "second step" looks like this (an inverse "first", then the eigenbasis, then the eigenvector basis, and then you've to multiply by the vector you wanted to transform in first place):

$(\mathbf{cb} \cdot \mathbf{eb}^2 \cdot \mathbf{cb}^{-1}) \cdot \mathbf{vec}$

With numpy:

```
# (cb*eb^2*cb_inv)*vec 
np.dot(np.dot(cb,np.dot(np.dot(eb,eb),cb_inv)),vec) # array([4, 4])
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
# t^2*vec
np.dot(t,np.dot(t,vec)) # array([4, 4])
```

I'm just seeking an intuitive explanation, because I feel like I'm missing something (or more than that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, change of basis is a type of translation in the sense of languages.

Let's say we have a linear transformation $T$, and on the standard basis vectors $e_{1}, e_{2}, \dots, e_{n}$ effecting $T$ is multiplication by some $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Let's call multiplying by $A$ "performing $T$ in English."

For general reasons, however, there is another language, *Diaglish*, with coordinate axes spanned by *eigenvectors* $v_{1}, v_{2}, \dots, v_{n}$. For each index $j$, the value $T(v_{j}) = \lambda_{j} v_{j}$ is a scalar multiple of $v_{j}$ for known *eigenvalues* $\lambda_{j}$. Since $T$ scales the scales the Diaglish coordinate axes, "performing $T$ in Diaglish" is multiplication by some diagonal matrix $D$.

The algebraic work of finding the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors amounts to compiling an English to Diaglish dictionary: the matrix $P^{-1}$ whose columns are the standard representations of the eigenvectors. The inverse matrix $(P^{-1})^{-1} = P$ translates Diaglish to English.

There are now two ways to think of our linear transformation:

1. Apply the transformation in Diaglish. (Multiply by $D$.)
2. (i) Translate from Diaglish to English (rightmost factor $P$), (ii) effect the transformation in English (middle factor $A$), and (iii) translate that output back to Diaglish (leftmost factor $P^{-1}$). (Multiply by $P^{-1}AP$.)

As matrices, we have $D = P^{-1}AP$, or $A = PDP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your code becomes more readable if you use

```
 vec2=M.dot(vec1)
 # or
 vec2=M @ vec1
 # instead of
 vec2=np.dot(M,vec1)
```

> But what I can't wrap my head around is why the "second step" looks
> like this (an inverse "first", then the eigenbasis, then the
> eigenvector basis, and then you've to multiply by the vector you
> wanted to transform in first place):

If you have a basis of vectors and you want to transfer something into that basis (express it as a combination of that basis vectors) then you need the inverse. Because if you take the result and multiply it with the basis then you get back the original. Another way to think about it:

If you have the i-th basis vector and you transform it you want it to be a 1 on the i-th position and all zeros otherwise.